# HTML5 video tag

Tags: html

Iam using safari version-5 and i need to run html5 VIDEO tag in this browser.I have used this code to run it...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">

  <source src="sample_mpeg4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
This is it
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

When i run this script nothing is displaying expect the statement "This is it".
Can any one please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
<video src="video.wmv"> Your browser doesnt support html5</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying...
still iam not getting any video.Is there any other way to run this?

Comment: its working, as we can see here; http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video

Comment: but i think we have to add controls="controls" to the video tag. so our new code is;
<video src="video.wmv" controls="controls"> Your browser doesnt support html5</video>